# websocket room security using socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am building an web-application with many moving parts. I need to emit websocket messages via redis, and I am therefor using the `socket.io-redis` (using nodejs) package and a normal socket.io client.

The problem boils down to private messages over this channel.

The absolute best solution for me would be making the clients subscribe to rooms with names like `eventtype-abc123`, where `abc123` is a random token that is stored as a cookie on the client, but also known to the backend api.
Is this considered efficient security? Or am I misunderstanding something with websockets?

I also need a public "room", and several people might subscribe to the same secret rooms. Using another authentication will complicate my setup a lot..